# Can we build a superconductor on the Moon and beam energy where needed?

Tags: superconductivity, moon, satellites, asteroids

Should we not build a superconductor facility on the moon ? We find a spot where the rays of the sun don’t provide heat. This should enable a superconductivity facility to operate due to the low temperature on the moon.

We then produce energy on the moon ie via solar energy, Helium 3 extraction, store the generated energy in a “super conductor” battery, and can then beam the generated energy into space, ie via a HAARP like facility. This could be used to power satellites, maybe even space shuttles, and possibly also to deal with asteroid threats, ie the proposed DE-Star lasers?

Comment: I don't understand your idea. For one, the moon doesn't have a permanently dark side (the same side (mostly) faces the earth, but that side is sometimes dark and somitimes sunlit). But even if it had, you would have a cold spot where is would be (comparatively) simple to keep a superconducting wire cool. How would that generate energy?

Comment: @Toffomat I thought so too, but apparently you can find such a spot on the moon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crater_of_eternal_darkness
(at)OP: No offense, but this sounds like science fiction and is imho better placed at worldbuilding.stackexchange.

Comment: @infinitezero Ah, OK, I didn't know that. Agree with you on the fiction part.

Comment: Yeah you need to clear up how you would expect this to generate energy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for input. I am new to this forum, so possibly this is not the right place. As for energy generation, your ideas are as good as mine: solar panels send energy to the superconductor. Helium 3 utilization, whatever. My point is simply that we should benefit from the possibility of a superconductor facility on the moon, I imagine there would be a large energy bonus as compared to normal conductivity, probably also in the transformation process, if a HAARP type facility were to be involved.

Comment: I think OP is asking whether it would make sense to have a giant superconducting battery storing energy on the moon. Then beam out energy as needed. If this is the correct understanding, then I recommend rewriting the question, because that certainly is not science fiction.

Comment: Great advice, thanks, I have just edited the question. On a more speculative note, I intuitively feel that superconductors hold so much more potential than just “zero resistance”. I’m thinking thoughts like particle accelerators (CERN style but smaller..), maybe even generate an energy surplus from continuous particle collisions. And possibly going into the realm of science fiction, I find it likely that using superconductors to generate electromagnetic fields may help tap the elusive zero point energy. But I imagine that’s a whole new topic in and of itself.

Comment: Particle accelerators already use superconductors...

Comment: Thanks for info, I feel it only validates  my point.

Answer (score 1):

Superconduction only means that the material at hand will have an electrical resisitance approaching 0. That does not mean that there is any energy being produced, only that you could channel existing current through it without -losses-. It is somewhat possible to induce a current in a superconductor, which then will hold the current going because there is no loss. Thats where some cool experiments stem from where you can float a magnet or a mini train over a circle of supercoductors. There is no energy being produced there too!

Comment: Thanks for the input.